# wp_insert_post not working fine

Tags: php, wordpress, post, cron

I am using **wp_insert_post** function to insert my posts but it is not working fine for me.

Here is my post_content

```
<div class="snippet"><strong>Wordpress Tutorial - Jetpack Plugin installieren &amp; konfigurieren</strong><br/><p>Wordpress Online Kurs unter http://wordpress-online-kurs.de Sie erhalten Tutorials zu den Wordpress Themen, wie Plugins, Theme, SEO ...<a href=https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DzjMtxin-hRA&ct=ga&cd=CAIyGmExYThkZTljMmU3MDQyZGE6Y29tOmVuOlVT&usg=AFQjCNGFOBEtFiT4f7zq6xl-xTbsW9uIVg target="_blank"></a><br /><a href=https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DzjMtxin-hRA&ct=ga&cd=CAIyGmExYThkZTljMmU3MDQyZGE6Y29tOmVuOlVT&usg=AFQjCNGFOBEtFiT4f7zq6xl-xTbsW9uIVg rel="nofollow" target='_blank'>See Original Article </a></p></div><div class="snippet"><strong>Preview Fargo - Responsive Creative WordPress Theme TFx</strong><br/><p>Preview and Download : http://fxtheme.com/themes/fargo-responsive-creative-wordpress-theme-tfx FARGO is a beautifully designed and visually ...<a href=https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DqjKCijxQR1M&ct=ga&cd=CAIyGmExYThkZTljMmU3MDQyZGE6Y29tOmVuOlVT&usg=AFQjCNGlUblc7rKI0OjRLqe1CChEfbpYmQ target="_blank"></a><br /><a href=https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DqjKCijxQR1M&ct=ga&cd=CAIyGmExYThkZTljMmU3MDQyZGE6Y29tOmVuOlVT&usg=AFQjCNGlUblc7rKI0OjRLqe1CChEfbpYmQ rel="nofollow" target='_blank'>See Original Article </a></p></div>
```

When I am adding this as manually it is inserting while I am using cron to insert it just insert post upto "SEO"

Code is :

```
$my_post = array('post_title'=>'test post','post_content'=>$array);
```

$content is the above data

Please help me to find out what the issue is

Thanks!

Comment: Add the actual code you have to the question

Comment: I'm having trouble with $post_content if it contains the string "http". The page is redirected to an error page.